# unwanted bulk emailing in PHP or smtp server

Tags: php, email

In my PHP I have the following code handling email if the configuration specifies not to use PEAR:

```
$headers = '';
foreach($this->headers as $key => $value)
  $headers .= "$key: $value\r\n";
foreach($addresses as $address)
{
  $headers .= "To: $address\r\n";
  if(!mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers))
    return FALSE;
}
```

As you can see the intention is for PHP::mail() to send on the email to the mail server one by one according to the addresses in the array $addresses. This has worked fine for a number of years.

I now have a user of my software who has a problem of repeat emails with varying numbers of email addresses on each. His configuration uses the code above so each email subject/content is sent multiple times to individual addresses but the email that arrives in each user mailbox shows multiple addresses in the To: field and some users report receiving the same email over 50 times.

I'm quite sure my code is not to blame (first time I've come across this in over 10 years using the code and in multiple installations) so I now have to ask if it is a problem with the smtp server PHP sends the email onto.

I'm not that familiar with such servers so:
a) are there some smtp server configurations that will take a stream of incoming individually addressed emails, assess the subject and content of each within a short period of time, decide they are the same email and then forward on a single email with multiple addresses in the To: field? It strikes me that any self-respecting smtp server might view this as an efficient mode of emailing but I don't know the terminology to google for.

b) If a) is what is happening, would bounced emails in the To: field generate repeat emails sent to all previous addresses in the To: field?

Thanks for the help and suggestions in advance.

Comment: Is there something that resets `$headers` between calls of `mail()` because, based on your snippet, that would be my guess

Comment: I would clearly say that indeed your code _is_ to blame here: with each iteration of the loop you add an address, the recipient list gets longer and longer! This code apparently never has been really tested!

Comment: Following your code example, you are adding new `To` header in every loop execution, building your headers list very long and script does behave properly imo. Why to append header with 'To' once you have an `$address` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exapleous code does deliver multiple `To` headers for `$headers` param of mail function. To set receiver it is enough to use an `$address` parameter. Your code should start to work properly when having one less line in it:

```
$headers = '';
foreach($this->headers as $key => $value) {
    $headers .= "$key: $value\r\n";
}

foreach($addresses as $address)
{
  // $headers .= "To: $address\r\n";
  if(!mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers))
      return FALSE;
}
```